# set background when using constraint layout

Tags: android, background, android-constraintlayout

I am using constraint layout as parent, and added multiple child using constraint. There are three views horizontally and I have to apply rounded corner background for two view only, which was achieved by linear layout previously. But with the help of constraint layout, I am not able to achieve this.

How can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

ConstraintLayout recently introduced the concept of constrainthelper which can be used to perform an action on a group of views. 'Group', which is used to toggle visibility of multiple view is subclass of this.

A constrainthelper which changes background of multiple views together is not yet a part of the stable release, but soon will be.

Until then, you can achieve a backround as in the example below, where 3 textview share a common background, using an View class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#AAA">

  <View
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#FFF"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView1" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="TextView" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1"
    tools:text="TextView" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
    tools:text="TextView" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

EDIT: [A nice blog on what to expect from ConstraintLayout 2.0](https://novemberfive.co/blog/what-to-expect-from-constraint-layout-2)

Comment: width and height 0dp is important!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with simple Image View following this steps:

- Put a Image view  before text views
- set Image view's **start, top** constraint to match first text view
- Set Image view's **end & bottom** constraint to match last text views

  This will gone stretch that `imageview` to a Rectangle defined by top-left of first view and bottom-right of last view.

  Note that ImageView must be before text views:

  ```
       <!--Background Image View-->
    <ImageView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:background="@drawable/lake"
          app:layout_goneMarginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

          <!--Top_LEFT by first view-->
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="heding"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/heding"

          <!--BOTTOM RIGHT by last view-->
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/info"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/info"
          />

          <!--first view-->
      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/heding"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_margin="8dp"
          android:text="Lake Tahoe "
          android:textSize="17sp"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/thumb"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/thumb"
          tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
          android:textColor="#FFF"
          tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

          <!--last view-->

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/info"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_margin="8dp"
          android:text="LakeTahoe is a large freshwater lake in Sierra Naveda"
          android:textSize="15sp"
          android:textColor="#FFF"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/thumb"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/thumb"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/heding"
          app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
          tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
          tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
          tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />
  ```

Result:

[image]